# How to store the return value of suspended function to a variable?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm trying to understand Kotlin couroutine. So here's my code (based on [this tutorial](https://johncodeos.com/how-to-make-post-get-put-and-delete-requests-with-retrofit-using-kotlin/)). To keep the code relatively simple, I deliberately avoid MVVM, LiveData, etc. Just Kotlin couroutine and Retrofit.

Consider this login process.

**ApiInterface.kt**

```
interface ApiInterface {

    // Login
    @POST("/user/validate")
    suspend fun login(@Body requestBody: RequestBody): Response<ResponseBody>

}
```

**ApiUtil.kt**

```
class ApiUtil {

    companion object {

        var API_BASE_URL = "https://localhost:8100/testApi"

        fun getInterceptor() : OkHttpClient {
            val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()

            logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

            val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .build()

            return  okHttpClient
        }

        fun createService() : ApiInterface {

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(getInterceptor())           
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(OJIRE_BASE_URL)
                .build()
            return retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)

        }
    }

   
    fun login(userParam: UserParam): String {
        val gson = Gson()
        val json = gson.toJson(userParam)
        var resp = ""
        val requestBody = json.toString().toRequestBody("application/json".toMediaTypeOrNull())

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val response = createService().login(requestBody)

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                if (response.isSuccessful){
                    val gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
                    val prettyJson = gson.toJson(
                        JsonParser.parseString(
                            response.body()
                                ?.string()
                        )
                    )
                    resp = prettyJson
                    Log.d("Pretty Printed JSON :", prettyJson)
                }
                else {
                    Log.e("RETROFIT_ERROR", response.code().toString())
                }
            }
        }

        return resp
    }
}
```

**LoginActivity.kt**

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    
        edtUsername = findViewById(R.id.edtUsername)
        edtPassword = findViewById(R.id.edtPassword)
        btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin)
        
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener {
            val api = ApiUtil()
            val userParam = UserParam(edtMobileNo.text.toString(), edtPassword.text.toString())
            val response = JSONObject(api.login(userParam))
            var msg = ""
            
            if (response.getString("message").equals("OK")){
                msg = "Login OK"
            }
            else {
                msg = "Login failed"
            }
            
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    
        }
    }
}
```

When debugging the login activity, the API response is captured properly on `prettyJson`
The problem is `resp` is still empty. Guess that's how async process work. What I want is to wait until the API call is completed, then the result can be nicely passed to `resp` as the return value of `login()`. How to do that?

Comment: You can use resp:(String) -> Unit as extra param in login() function and after response catch that in view (in Activity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you got several things wrong here. We'll try to fix them all.

First, the main problem you described is that you need to acquire `resp` in `login()` synchronously. You got this problem only because you first launched an asynchronous operation there. Solution? Don't do that, get the response synchronously by removing `launch()`. I guess `withContext()` is also not required as we don't do anything that requires the main thread. After removing them the code becomes much simpler and fully synchronous.

Last thing that we need to do with `login()` is to make it suspendable. It needs to wait for the request to finish, so it is a suspend function. The resulting `login()` should be similar to:

```kotlin
suspend fun login(userParam: UserParam): String {
    val gson = Gson()
    val json = gson.toJson(userParam)
    val requestBody = json.toString().toRequestBody("application/json".toMediaTypeOrNull())

    val response = createService().login(requestBody)

    return if (response.isSuccessful){
        val gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
        gson.toJson(
            JsonParser.parseString(
                response.body()
                    ?.string()
            )
        )
    }
    else {
        Log.e("RETROFIT_ERROR", response.code().toString())
        // We need to do something here
    }
}
```

Now, as we converted `login()` to suspendable, we can't invoke it from the listener directly. Here we really need to launch asynchronous operation, but we won't use `CoroutineScope()` as you did in your example, because it leaked background tasks and memory. We will use `lifecycleScope` like this:

```kotlin
btnLogin.setOnClickListener {
    val api = ApiUtil()
    val userParam = UserParam(edtMobileNo.text.toString(), edtPassword.text.toString())
    
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        val response = JSONObject(api.login(userParam))
        var msg = ""

        if (response.getString("message").equals("OK")){
            msg = "Login OK"
        }
        else {
            msg = "Login failed"
        }

        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Above code may not be fully functional. It is hard to provide working examples without all required data structures, etc. But I hope you get the point.

Also, there are several other things in your code that could be improved, but I didn't touch them to not confuse you.

Comment: Also, I see that most of misconceptions you used is actually from the tutorial you linked. I don't have a better one, but I suggest not using it. Maybe this is just me, but it is full of anti-patterns. `CoroutineScope().launch()` - this code leaks background tasks and associated resources/memory. There is no need to use `Dispatchers.IO` to invoke Retrofit suspend functions. Switching to `Dispatchers.Main` just because we finished IO is also not required.

Comment: I see. couroutines in not as simple as good old' `AsyncTask`, definitely need more time to study the concept. BTW, if the couroutine isn't wrapped in `lifecycleScope.launch`, it will continue to run even though the user move to different activity, yes?

Comment: Actually, I think they're easier to use. They're just new knowledge to acquire and people tend to use them with patterns that don't really fit to them. But this is definitely arguable - many people see them as complicated.

Comment: Regarding `lifecycleScope.launch`: yes and no ;-) Without it the code would not at all compile. We can't invoke suspend functions from not suspend ones. Usually, we bridge these two worlds with either `runBlocking()` which blocks the invoking thread or by launching the operation asynchronously using `launch()`/`async()`. But yes, you are correct, `lifecycleScope` makes sure that background operation will be canceled when we leave the activity. `CoroutineScope().lauch()` doesn't do this.